# rails: how to "re"generate view files after changing/adding fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I first ran a scaffolding command e.g.,

rails generate scaffold User

Now, I went to app/models/user.rb and added a bunch of fields

What I would like is to now run a command that regenerates the view files in app/views/users/ such that _form.html.erb now contains HTML for the fields that I added above.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be to use the [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) gem.

Then your form could look like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs %>
  <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

This form snippet works as following description.

> This renders a set of inputs (one for most columns in the database table, and one for each ActiveRecord belongs_to-association), followed by default action buttons (an input submit button).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same command again with `--skip-migration` and specify new fields like below

```
rails generate scaffold User existing_field:string new_field:string --skip-migration
```

Note that you must use `--skip-migration`, otherwise scaffold generation will fail with an error that migration already exists. You'll be prompted with what all files you want to overwrite. Overwrite everything except model file because you have already made some changes in there.

Also, since you are adding new fields, you should update your migration file accordingly.

**ALTERNATE**

Delete your existing migration file and generate scaffold like before and overwrite selected files.

```
rails generate scaffold User existing_field:string new_field:string
```

Comment: Alright. That should work. However, I was looking for some easy way wherein 1) I add the fields manually in db/migrate file  2) then run I run some command that reads the fields for the table and updates the view file automatically. But then again it defeats the purpose of migration files as one can add fields later on etc. etc.